# Set current only one item with RegexVoter from KnpMenu

Tags: php, symfony, knpmenubundle, knpmenu

I use the regexVoter from knpMenu like this

```
//This is on my createMenuAction
$this->matchingRoute($menu);

/**
 * @param $menu
 *
 * @return bool
 */
private function matchingRoute($menu)
{
    foreach ($menu->getChildren() as $child) {
        $childRegex = $child->getAttribute('regex');

        $voter = new RegexVoter($childRegex);
        $voterTest = $voter->matchItem($child);

        if ($voterTest == true && $this->request->getUri()) {
            $child->setCurrent(true);
        } else {
            $child->setCurrent(false);
        }
    }
}
```

This is working but setting me a current class to all child with a regex attributes. This voter compare childs regex with their route so it become true all the time.

I tried to add `return true;`

```
if ($voterTest == true && $this->request->getUri()) {
    $child->setCurrent(true);
    return true;
} else {
    $child->setCurrent(false);
}
```

But this set current class on the first child who return true with regexVoter.

Should i check this regex against the current route with this voter ?

How can i use this voter to set current class on the good child ?

Thanks,